# Rails testing using Rspec and FactoryBot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am new to rails rspec testing, I currently need to created nested data structure and using factorybot for data. And while it works for controller testing. Its not letting me do simple Factorybot.create(:model).
I have searched a lot. But didn't seem to find or understand a solution.
So, data structure i need to create is something like:

```
"email":"",
"name":"",
"personalDetail":{
"height":"",
"weight":"",
"color":""
}
"address":{
"street":"",
"postal_code":""
},
"experience":""
}
```

(**note. this not association related, data in controller is received in such a way. There is no relationship involved)
 while i am currently achieving this structure using

```
initialize_with{{
"email":"",
"name":"",
"personalDetail":{
"height":"",
"weight":"",
"color":""
}
"address":{
"street":"",
"postal_code":""
},
"experience":""
}}
```

its works for controller testing but it i'm not able to change key value while testing like:

```
FactoryBot.create(:model, name:"xyz")
```

, and also is not working for FactoryBot.create(:model), which is giving me error of

** Api::V1::someController get #index 
     Failure/Error: FactoryBot.create(:model)

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `save!' for #<Hash:0x0000563db7324060>
 # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/somecontroller_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
 # -e:1:in `<main>' **
```

So, my question is how can i generate this structure using FactoryBot usual method. i.e

```
factory :job_application do
    field1 { "" }
    field2 { "" }
  end
```

so that i can use it usual way.

Comment: Are you trying to create a literal Hash?

Comment: no, i  figured out what i was doing wrong, thanks to your comment. but still unable to write test, i will have to look some more.

Answer (score 1):

`factory :job_application` will guess that you want to make an object of the class `JobApplication`. To make a `Hash` you need to make it explicit. See [Defining Factories](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Defining_factories).

```
factory :job_application, class: Hash
```

Because `Hash.new` does not take a bunch of key/value pairs, you need to override the default initialization behavior. I've found the simplest thing to do is to return the `attributes` of the factory. See [Custom Construction](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Custom_Construction).

Those use symbol keys, you want string keys, so we use [`deep_stringify_keys`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-deep_stringify_keys). This also takes care of cloning `attributes` just in case.

```
factory :job_application, class: Hash do
  initialize_with do
    attributes.deep_stringify_keys
  end
end
```

Now you can add attributes in the normal way.

```
factory :job_application, class: Hash do
  email { "jorb@coachz.biz" }

  initialize_with do
    attributes.deep_stringify_keys
  end
end
```

Because there is no `save` method, you can only `build` these Hash factories.

```
# Yes
jorb = FactoryBot.build(:job_application)

# No
jorb = FactoryBot.create(:job_application)
```

I find myself doing this a lot, so I've built a `string_hash` factory to inherit from.

```
factory :string_hash, class: Hash do
  initialize_with do
    attributes.deep_stringify_keys
  end
end

factory :job_application, parent: :string_hash do
  email { "jorb@coachz.biz" }
end
```

---

If you want nested hashes, I suggest you make additional factories and associate them together. This allows you to easily change the values in the nested hashes.

Associations default to using `create`, we need to explicitly `build` our associations. See [Associations](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations).

```
factory :address, parent: :string_hash do
  street { "Ahead St." }
  postal_code { "12345" }
end

factory :job_application, parent: :string_hash do
  association :address, strategy: :build

  email { "jorb@coachz.biz" }
  name { "Coach Z" }
end

build(:job_application,
  address: build(:address, street: "Sesame St.")
)
```

---

Do ask yourself whether it makes sense to [define these as models](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html). This makes them work with normal factories and features like validation and you can add methods and all that good stuff.

Since this is data you receive in a controller it might benefit from having validations and methods. See [ActiveModel Form Objects by ThoughtBot](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/activemodel-form-objects).

```
class JobApplication
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :email, :name, :address

  validates :name, :email, presence: true
end

class Address
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :street, :postal_code
end

factory :address do
  street { "Ahead St." }
  postal_code { "12345" }
end

factory :job_application do
  # Can't save a Model either.
  association :address, strategy: :build

  email { "jorb@coachz.biz" }
  name { "Coach Z" }
end
```

Comment: sorry, i think don't fully understand what you are suggesting. and my question may have confused you to some level. what i want is not a hash, but i'm receiving data params in controller in such nested way. i need to make a factory that will be accepted by controller while testing

Comment: That should be a hash which is passed into `params`. `get :create, params: build(:job_application)`. [Something like this.](https://gist.github.com/schwern/faa6984a6b8881aa6f527a5c9eaf4095) (not tested)